# Expand/Collapse jQuery treetable

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, treetable

I am using the treetable library from jQuery and I am trying to do an accordion type-like behaviour, such that when I open one of the levels and it expands, I want to collapse the other level that was previously opened. I do not know how to implement this behaviour using the jQuery treetable library.

This is the code for my treetable:

```
function buildTreeTable(tree){

    $("#example").treetable({
        expandable:     true,
        onNodeExpand:   nodeExpand,
        onNodeCollapse: nodeCollapse
    });

function nodeExpand () {
        getNode(this.id); 
 }


function nodeCollapse () {
         console.log("Collapsed: " + this.id);
    }

function getNode(parentNode){
        id = parentNode;
        console.log("The new var is", id);
        console.log("The id of the parent is: ", parentNode);
        var parentNode = $("#example").treetable("node", parentNode);
        $("#example").treetable("unloadBranch", parentNode);
    console.log("parent node",parentNode);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Idea ... you can hold ID of node which you are opening and then you can collapseAll() and next expand the node which ID you remember in variable .expandNode(id).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Initially collapse all the rows in Treegrid tables.
2. Then, in 'onExpand' function check whether the previous node is expanded. If it is expanded collapse that node. (Note: I have stored the previous id in temp variable here.)

Now, it works fine as a normal 'collapse & accordian'

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var temp = "";
    $('.tree').treegrid({
        'expanderExpandedClass': 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus',
        'expanderCollapsedClass': 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus',
        'initialState': 'collapsed',
        **'onExpand': function () {
            if ($(document.getElementById(temp)).treegrid('isExpanded')) {
                $(document.getElementById(temp)).treegrid('collapse');
            }
            temp = $(this).attr("id");
        }**
    });
});
```